# VAADIN 14 TreeGrid Keyboard Navigation not supported?

Tags: navigation, keyboard, vaadin14, treegrid

A TreeGrid component is used to navigate in our application. It works well when using the mouse. But we want to support the use of the keyboard also. It seems that in VAADIN 8 this was supported:
https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-treegrid#components.treegrid.keyboard
but it is not supported anymore with VAADIN 14? https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-tree-grid/
Did I miss out some documentation?

Question 1: Is keyboard navigation supported or not? What actions are necessary to use it?
Question 2: If it is not supported, what is the workaround? I did try to use the keyboard shortcuts (https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/components/tutorial-flow-shortcut) but could not construct a working solution...

What do we need exactly:

a) Navigating UP and DOWN the tree by using the appropiate arrow keys.
b) Expanding / collapsing the tree when using the LEFT / RIGHT arrow keys.
c) Opening (selecting) the corresponding view, when the user hits the ENTER key. (So it is necessary to know which of the tree elements has the focus and receives the ENTER event.)

Comment: I think your question is somewhat similar to this feature ticket https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/97

Comment: Hi Tatu, thank you. Keyboard assistence like described in https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/treegrid/treegrid-1.html would be indeed helpfull.